# How to get data in an sql foreign key using asp.net entity framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, foreign-keys, relational-database

I'm now trying to incorporate relational database in my project. Before the implementation of rdbms in my project, normally i would normally be able to access my desired value through this code:

```
public static string guitar { get; set; }
public static List<stringInstrumentItem> GetGuitarItems()
{
    List<stringInstrumentItem> list2 = new List<stringInstrumentItem>();

        MusicStoreDBEntities obj2 = new MusicStoreDBEntities();
        list2 = (from g in obj2.stringInstrumentItems where g.brand == guitar select g).ToList();


    return list2;

}
```

But now that i already set a foreign key in my sql script, the g.brand is not working because it does not contain a text value anymore, it is now an int called brandId. To better understand my problem, here is the sql script for stringInstrumentItem table. This is where I set the foreign key brandId referencing the brand table and its primary key.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[stringInstrumentItem](
[itemId] [int] NOT NULL,
[type] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[brandId] [int] FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES brand(brandId),
[model] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[price] [float] NOT NULL,
[itemimage1] [varchar](255) NULL,
[itemimage2] [varchar](255) NULL,
[description] [text] NOT NULL,
[necktype] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[body] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[fretboard] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[fret] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[bridge] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[neckpickup] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[bridgepickup] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[hardwarecolor] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[itemId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = 
OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Now here is the brand table. This is the table that stringInstrumentItem is referring to.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[brand](
[brandId] [int] NOT NULL,
[type] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[image] [varchar](255) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[brandId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = 
OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF 
GO
```

My goal is to be able to access the value of a field called name in brand table through stringInstrumentItem table using asp.net and entity framework. I haven't really found answers for this. I hope you guys can help me on this one.

Comment: The simplest approach is to do it in two steps. Get the id first and then find an object with that id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have proper relationship between those two inside MusicStoreDBEntities, you should be able to access brand name like `g.brand.name`.

```
list2 = (from g in obj2.stringInstrumentItems 
        where g.brand.name == guitar select g).ToList();
                     ^^^^^^
```

Otherwise, you will have to manually join them like this -

```
list2 = (from g in obj2.stringInstrumentItems
        join b in obj2.brand
        on g.brandId equals b.brandId
        where b.name == guitar
        select g).ToList();
```

Comment: How about in this format "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stringInstrumentItem WHERE brandId LIKE @brand" ??? how will I get the field called name in brand table through stringInstrumentItem in this format???

Comment: You can use `.Count()` instead of `.ToList()`. Count returns integer value.

Comment: yes agreed but i did not meant using entity framework linq. what i meant was how to do it in a regular sql script like this: "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stringInstrumentItem WHERE brandId LIKE @brand". I apologize for the lack of explanation in my question.

Comment: Could you please create a new question? I'm happy to take a look at it.

Comment: please checkout my new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44828553/how-to-get-data-in-an-sql-foreign-key-using-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    list2 = MusicStoreDBEntities.stringInstrumentItem. 
Where(x=> x.brand.name == "guitar").Select(x=> x).ToList();
```