# How to get data in a SQL Server foreign key using asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

This question is somewhat similar and related to my previous question [How to get data in an sql foreign key using asp.net entity framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44825494/how-to-get-data-in-an-sql-foreign-key-using-asp-net-entity-framework) so I will be using the same SQL Server tables.

This time, instead of accessing the foreign key value through Entity Framework, I want to know how to do it in a regular SQL script like this (take note, the script that I'm talking about is inside the `string.Format`):

```
public static void getRowNumber(string brand)
{
    string query = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stringInstrumentItem WHERE brandId LIKE @brand");

    conn1.Open();

    command1.CommandText = query;
    command1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("brand", brand));

    Int32 count = (Int32)command1.ExecuteScalar();

    conn1.Close();

    command1.Parameters.Clear();

    AddASPXAndCSFile.X = count;
}
```

Just to recap, I have two SQL Server tables called `stringInstrumentItem` and `brand`. I created the foreign key in the table `stringInstrumentItem` referring to the primary key of the table `brand`. So I'm attempting to access the column `name` in table `brand` through `stringInstrumentItem`.

As you can see, I'm attempting to access the value in table `brand` through `brandId`, which does not work.

Hope you guys can help me on this one. Cheers!

Comment: What's the datatype of `brandId`? Usually an `ID` column is int.

Comment: BrandID sounds like an integer, you cannot do like on that

Comment: I believe you need the `@` sign in this `new SqlParameter("@brand", brand)` to access the parameter.

Comment: @WEI_DBA - yes its an integer but i want to access the field name in brand..how do i achieve that?

Comment: in what table is the field name brand ?

Comment: @GuidoG - the field name is within the table brand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it seems like a simple query -

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stringInstrumentItem 
WHERE brandId IN (SELECT brandId FROM brand WHERE name LIKE @brand)
```

Please make use you have `@` and `%` *(based on your requirement)*.

```
command1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@brand", "%" + brand + "%"));
```

Comment: oh I see. I was not aware that you can nest the sql script like that. cool info.

Comment: Hi! If your interested in answering another question, here's the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44847998/how-to-get-data-of-sql-foreign-key-in-asp-net-repeater

Comment: Hi Win! unfortunately i have deleted the question regarding the foreign key because i decided to try other solutions but if your interested for more questions, i have another one up, check it out if your available https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44872117/asp-net-image-not-working?noredirect=1#comment76723005_44872117